# OpenMP: Causes for heap corruption, anyone?

Tags: c++, c, dll, openmp, visual-c++-2005

**EDIT:** I can run the same program twice, simultaneously without any problem - how can I duplicate this with OpenMP or with some other method?

This is the basic framework of the problem.

```
//Defined elsewhere
class SomeClass
{
public:
  void Function()
  {
    // Allocate some memory
    float *Data;
    Data = new float[1024];

    // Declare a struct which will be used by functions defined in the DLL
    SomeStruct Obj;
    Obj = MemAllocFunctionInDLL(Obj);

    // Call it
    FunctionDefinedInDLL(Data,Obj);

    // Clean up
    MemDeallocFunctionInDLL(Obj);
    delete [] Data;        
  }
}

void Bar()
{
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(int j = 0;j<10;++j)
   {
     SomeClass X;
     X.Function();
   }
}
```

I've verified that when some memory is attempted to be deallocated through `MemDeallocFunctionInDLL()`, the `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer()` assertion fails.

Is this because both threads are writing to the same memory?

So to fix this, I thought I'd make `SomeClass` private (this is totally alien to me, so any help is appreciated).

```
void Bar()
{
   SomeClass X;
   #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(X)
   for(int j = 0;j<10;++j)
   {         
     X.Function();
   }
}
```

And *now* it fails when it tries to **allocate** memory in the beginning for `Data`.

**Note:** I can make changes to the DLL if required

**Note:** It runs perfectly without `#pragma omp parallel for`

**EDIT:** Now `Bar` looks like this:

```
void Bar()
{
   int j
   #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(j)
   for(j = 0;j<10;++j)
   {
     SomeClass X;         
     X.Function();
   }
}
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Maybe not related, but memory allocated with new [] should be deleted with delete [].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out MemAllocFunctionInDLL, FunctionDefinedInDLL, MemDeallocFunctionInDLL are **thread-safe**, or **re-entrant**. In other words, do these functions static variables or shared variables? In such case, you need to make it sure these variables are not corrupted by other threads.

The fact without omp-for is fine could mean you didn't correctly write some functions to be thread-safe.

I'd like to see what kind of memory allocation/free functions has been used in Mem(Alloc|Dealloc)FunctionInDLL.

**Added**: I'm pretty sure your functions in DLL is not thread-safe. You can run this program concurrently without problem. Yes, it should be okay unless your program uses system-wide shared resources (such as global memory or shared memory among processes), which is very rare. In this case, no shared variables in threads, so your program works fine.

But, invoking these functions in **mutithreads** (that means in a single process) crashes your program. It means there are some shared variables among threads, and it could have been corrupted.

It's not a problem of OpenMP, but just a multithreading bug. It could be simple to solve this problem. Please take a look the DLL functions whether they are safe to be called in concurrent by many threads.

**How to privatize static variables**

Say that we have such global variables:

```
static int  g_data;
static int* g_vector = new int[100];
```

Privatization is nothing but a creating **private** copy for each thread.

```
int  g_data[num_threads];
int* g_vector[num_threads];
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
  g_vector[i] = new int[100];
```

And, then any references on such variables are

```
// Thread: tid
g_data[tid] = ...
.. = g_vector[tid][..]
```

Yes, it's pretty simple. However, this sort of code may have a [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) problem. But, false sharing is a matter of performance, not correctness.

First, just try to privatize any static and global variables. Then, check it correctness. Next, see the speedup you would get. If the speedup is scalable (say 3.7x faster on quad core), then it's okay. But, in case of low speedup (such as 2x speedup on quad core), then you probably look at the false sharing problem. To solve false sharing problem, all you need to do is just putting some padding in data structures.

Comment: A possible immediate workaround (and it's stupid!) would be opening a DLL instance in the SomeClass::Function.

And, allocation/deallocation in DLL are just malloc/free?

Comment: @Minjang: You were right: I found a truckload of `static` variables in the code. So, I'm considering re-writing it and making it thread-safe or rewriting `Bar` to fork off two processes running the DLL's functions.

Comment: Nice to hear that :) In this case, you need to do 'privatization' of static variables. If the DLL code was written neatly, it may be quite simple. If this is so hard, then, as you said, forking multiple processes would be an workaround.

Comment: How would I "privatize" static variables?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
delete Data
```

you must write

```
delete [] Data;
```

Wherever you do new [], make sure to use delete [].

It looks like your problem is not specific to openmp. Did you try to run your application without including #pragma parallel?

Comment: true, but that wouldn't make it crash, just delete the first float leaving 1023 leaked.

Comment: I guess you cannot be sure of the effects of undefined  behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly without `#pragma omp parallel for`

Comment: It looks like without knowing the code of your DLL we could not help you more. By the way, is DLL compiled with openmp support?

Comment: Yes, it's compiled with OpenMP support.

Answer (score 2):

default(shared) means all variables are shared between threads, which is not what you want. Change that to default(none).

Private(X) will make a copy of X for each thread, however, none of them will be initialised so any construction will not necessarily be performed.

I think you'd be better with your initial approach, put a breakpoint in the Dealloc call, and see what the memory pointer is and what it contains. You can see the [guard bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) to tell if the memory has been overwritten at the end of a single call, or after a thread.

Incidentally, I am assuming this works if you run it once, without the omp loop?